# Energy loss with proton radiation

Tags: electromagnetism, particle-physics, electromagnetic-radiation

I wanted to estimate relative energy loss related with radiation for proton $\frac{\Delta \epsilon}{\epsilon}$ in accelerator in which protons get energy about $\epsilon$ ~ 7 TeV and the circumference is 27 km. It looks simple but I don't know how to start.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: maybe this link will help https://s3.cern.ch/inspire-prod-files-1/19d7c1e138bc64d91bc43db5f87e27ac

Comment: Or just https://farside.ph.utexas.edu/teaching/em/lectures/node130.html  The fully relativistic formula ai at the end. You need a bit of algebra. One does recover Frederic Thomas formula by integrating in time over one turn, since the final factor in the expression in "farside" is $(1-u^2/c^2)$ and thus reduces $\gamma^6$ to $\gamma^4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The radiation loss can be obtained from Larmor's formula.
Larmor's formula provides the power loss of an electrical particle when it is accelerated.
Integrating the radiation power loss over the revolution time in the accelerator

$$\Delta E_{rad} =\oint P_{rad} dt$$

one gets

$$\Delta E = \frac{e^2}{3\epsilon_0 (m_p c^2)^4 }\frac{E^4}{R}$$

where $e$ is the elementary charge, $\epsilon_0$ the electrical vacuum permitivity, $m_p$ the proton mass and $E$ the energy of the circulating proton and $R$ the radius of the accelerator. This is the energy loss per turn.

Note that due to the large mass of the proton compared to the mass of the electron the radiation loss is much smaller as for electrons, but at energies of the LHC the effect nevertheless is sensible.

Comment: @Alfred There is $(m_pc^2)^4$ in the denominator. Or do you mean the $3\epsilon_0$ should not be there ?

Comment: Yeah, indeed it's my mistake. I will correct it. Thank you